# Gitkraken - Filter all commits by author

Tags: git, github, client, gitkraken

I am trying to filter all the commits done by an user. Right now it just go to specific commit.

This feature I found in source tree but couldn't find the same in gitkraken.

Comment: `gitkraken` (v4.1.1) does have a feature to search by `author name`. Click on `Search Commits` and just type in the author name.

Comment: You might like to check out Git Extensions (Windows only). GitKraken is great at 2am with its dark theme, but the feature set is pretty light. https://gitextensions.github.io/. I've literally used a dozen clients...and Git Extensions is head and shoulders above anything else I've used for performance and features.